# How to check Model properties in unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, razor, moq

I have a `Action` as bellow:

```
public ActionResult SaveAndExit()
{
    ViewModel1 viewModel = new ViewModel1();

    return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

In Unit Test I want to check if view `Reg` in viewModel is null or not. any suggestions please

Test:

```
//act
var result = controller.SaveAndExit(viewModel) as ViewResult;

//assert
//Assert.IsNotNull(!result.Model["Reg"].Equals(null));
```

Comment: That assert is quite confusing... You are checking if something is not null, then checking that result is not null. Does this not work on its own? Assert.IsNotNull(result.Model["Reg"])

Comment: Right. You are calling `Assert.IsNotNull(boolean)`

Comment: @GazWinter this line of code is wrong. model does not allow to access its properties their. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would tend to write the asserts as follows (using Microsoft test framework asserts here - you didn't specify nunit):

```
// Act
ActionResult result = controller.SaveAndExit(viewModel);

// Assert
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));
ViewResult viewResult = (ViewResult)result;

Assert.IsInstanceOfType(viewResult.Model, typeof(ViewModel1));
ViewModel1 model = (ViewModel1)viewResult.Model;

Assert.IsNotNull(model.Reg);
```

Comment: Hi, in debug model, reg is null but its throwing Exception `Assert.IsNotNull failed.`

Comment: @user1211185 That's the point of the Assert.  You are asserting that Reg isn't null, and if it is, then your test should fail.

Comment: **Worked**   replaced the `Assert.IsNotNull(model.Reg);` with `Assert.IsNull(model.Reg);`....  many thanks

Comment: @user1211185 Glad to help, but make sure that is what you intended the code to do - don't just fix the test lol.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests should test business logic. You don't need to write a unit test just for checking some property for null.

Comment: Unless perhaps you're fixing a bug that is throwing a null reference exception when rendering the view. No reason this isn't a "worthwhile" test.

Comment: @user1211185, I suggest to take a look at [Unit Testing Best Practices](http://osherove.com/videos/2009/8/25/unit-testing-best-practices.html). Sure this link will be useful for you anyway.